# What is the relation between degeneracy and density of states?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, density-of-states

The definition of degeneracy and density of states (DOS) looks resembling to each other, what is the relation and difference between these two concepts? And is there a mathematical relation or formula between these two physical quantities?

Comment: See the final equation of [the Wikipedia definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_of_states#Definition) and the commentary attached to it.

Answer (score 1):

So in simple probability theory, we have two different notions that we unify. One is the common discrete notion of probability, you roll a die and with probability 1/6 the roll comes up as a five. The other is a continuous notion of probability, approximately like my computer’s `rand()` function, it should generate a value between 0 and 1, it should not be biased towards any of the numbers in the middle, and I want to think of this continuously.

A way to unify these is the **cumulative distribution function**, $F(x)$ being the probability that some outcome is less than or equal to $x$. If you have a discrete probability then $F$ will have discontinuities, so for a single die $F$ looks like a “staircase” with 6 even steps, for `rand()` $F$ looks like a ramp.

If you take the derivative of $F$ you get the *probability density function*, and technically it is undefined at discontinuities, but we are physicists and we can crudely hack around this with the [Dirac δ-function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) for our purposes. In the continuous case $f(x)~\Delta x$ gives us the approximate probability that the outcome is between $x$ and $x+\Delta x$.

Now, why am I talking about probabilities?

If you take away the criterion that probabilities must sum to one, probability theory becomes a theory of densities of physical quantities. And so something like the density of states has a similar problem: **sometimes** we want to think of a whole bunch of states of different energies spread out mostly continuously, the number of states with energy between $E$ and $E+\Delta E$ is $\Delta N = D(E)~\Delta E$.

But very often with energies we are actually dealing with discrete energy levels from quantum mechanics and if there's no fine/hyperfine splitting or whatever of the energy level, then we have a bunch of different states that all have the same energy, the states are **not** spread out continuously but there is just $n$ of them at some energy $E_0$. Again, $D(E)$ can contain these with a term $n~\delta(E-E_0)$, but we also speak of $n$ as the **degeneracy of the energy level.**

So for example if you have photons in a box and the polarization doesn't matter, you might have a degeneracy factor from the two different polarizations of photons that you've got in there. If you have electrons then they frequently have a spin degeneracy when your Hamiltonian doesn't couple to spin. I'm not a particle physicist so I don't know this for a fact but I would bet that there would be a situation in which you would have something like neutrino flavor degeneracy, I have some gravitational well trapping neutrinos and there are six times as many states as you would expect because they could be electron or mu or tau neutrinos or their antipatticles, gravity doesn't care much.

That's degeneracy.